# PHP (+ MaterializeCSS) Contact Form Not sending message

Tags: php, html, css, materialize

I made a contact form using materializeCSS and php.  I have it running on a localhost with this nice little program that listens to port25 so I know what's sending through.  Everything sends through except the message. On my mail.php there is an error with the "message on line 3".  The other data does send (echo: "thank you" shows.  here's the code...

```
<?php $name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent = "From: $name \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "cmontgomery279@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
?>




 <div class="row" id="contact-row">
<form action="mail.php" method="POST" class="col s12">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <input id="first_name" type="text" class="validate" name="name">
      <label for="first_name">Full Name</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <input id="email" type="text" class="validate" name="email">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <textarea id="textarea1" class="materialize-textarea" type="text" name="messsage"></textarea>
      <label for="textarea1">Message</label>
    </div>
  </div>
   <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your PHP you refer to `$_POST['message']`, but the name of the textarea is *messsage* (with 3 *s*). That's why PHP throws an error. Correct the textarea's name to *message* and it'll work.

```
<textarea id="textarea1" class="materialize-textarea" type="text" name="message"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i'm still confused...in my textarea I have name="message" isn't that the textareas name?

Comment: Never mind I get it now i had messsages thank you so much!